# Limit of a sum involving binomials and gammas

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

After playing a bit with some probabilities, I ended up with this:

$P(X=n) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \gamma(s, \frac{k}{\theta})$

Where $\gamma(s,x) = \int_{0}^{x} t^{s-1}e^{-t} dt$ (incomplete gamma function). I have the feeling that this converges for $n \to \inf$ as I plotted it for $k=0.1, \theta=21$ up to $n=30$ but I could not figure out a method yet.

In short, how to solve
$\lim \limits_{n \to \inf} \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \gamma(s, \frac{k}{\theta})$ ?

Comment: If this is indeed a probability distribution, then shouldn't $P(X=n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: What is $X$ here?

Comment: This is not a probability distribution, X is the number of times an event occurs n days consecutively, with a dependence between days.